# Safari displace sticky table header

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari, sticky

I have an application on which I need sticky headers. It works normally with Chrome and other browsers, but Safari doesn't, although documentation says that it should.

This is the code: (you should run it with Safari to not work)

```css
.container{
    padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;
    overflow: scroll;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height:10rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
}

.my_table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
}

.my_table thead,
.my_table thead th,
.my_table thead td {
      border-top: 0px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0062cc;
  
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <table class='my_table table'>
    <thead><tr><th><div>Header</div></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How do I fix this? 
I read about the problem if the parent `overflow` is `auto`, but mine is `scroll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set sticky only for `.my_table thead th` to work for safari and chrome

```css
.container{
    padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;
    overflow: scroll;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height:10rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
}

.my_table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
}

.my_table thead th {
      border-top: 0px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0062cc;
  
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <table class='my_table table'>
    <thead><tr><th><div>Header</div></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row</td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```